# Solving a differential equation with involving $e$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = e^{yx}+\frac yx$$

I'm trying to solve the differential equation. Here is part of my attempt:
[image]

I know that i have to integrate both sides of the equation but when I try to integrate my answer doesn´t match with the book´s answer.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Sorry where you read chain rule in fact it was used the product rule.

Comment: Please check out the links I provided and convert the image into MathJax. You can basically use the familiar LaTeX commands, equations starting with `$$` and use alignment like this: `$$\begin{align*} a & = b \\ \Rightarrow a + c & = b + c \end{align*}$$` $$\begin{align*} a & = b \\ \Rightarrow a + c & = b + c \end{align*}$$

Comment: What's the book answer?

Comment: y=-x Lg*lg*(C/x)

Comment: @ViniciusL.Beserra: If that is indeed the case, then you've misspelled your differential equation. In order for $y(x)=-x~\ln\ln\dfrac Cx$ to be a solution, the functional equation should read $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=e^{^{\Large y/x}}+\dfrac yx$

Comment: No, I didn´t mispelled the equation. In the book it is as I posted here.

Comment: "Thanks Alex, I will be take about it." Thirteen days later...

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that the book answer you cited is $y(x)=-x~\ln\ln\dfrac Cx~,~$ it follows that you've

misspelled the original equation, meaning that the question is actually supposed to read $y'(x)=$

$=\exp\bigg(\dfrac yx\bigg)+\dfrac yx~,~$ which begs for a substitution of the form $u(x)=\dfrac{y(x)}x~,~$ yielding $(x\cdot u)~'$

$=e^u+u.~$ But $(x\cdot u)~'=x\cdot u'+u\iff x~\dfrac{du}{dx}=e^u\iff\dfrac{dx}x=\dfrac{du}{e^u}~.$ I believe you can

take it from here.

Comment: As I said before I didn´t misspelled the original funcion. It is as in the book.

Comment: @ViniciusL.Beserra: If so, then the book itself contains a typographic error. You can see this for yourself by noticing that the solution presented in the book does not fulfill the equation.

Comment: Thanks Lucian, but in fact I would like someone unmark my question as -1.